# Group by and filter django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following data:

```
1, Red, Audi
2, Black, Audi
3, Black, BMW
```

I want to get all rows that have both `Red` and `Black` (and only them) colors for the same car.

In this case I expect 1 and 2 in result, because `Audi` is both `Red` and `Black`, but not 3, since there is no `Red` `BMW`.

How to achieve it with django orm?

```
class Car(Model):
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True,
                   default=uuid.uuid4,
                   editable=False)
    color = WordField(db_index=True, max_length=75)
    name = WordField(db_index=True, max_length=75)
```

Comment: How did you define your models? We can't help much if you don't show us your code.

Comment: Updated version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try approach like this:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, Q, Count, IntegerField


color_filter = Q(color="Red") | Q(color="Black")
cars = Car.objects.annotate(
    count=Subquery(
        Car.objects.filter(color_filter, name=OuterRef('name'))
            .values('name')
            .annotate(count=Count('name'))
            .values('count'), output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).filter(color_filter, count=2)
```

Comment: name__in=... evaluates the queryset, and it can be very huge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how (or if) this translates to django ORM, but if you're willing to do a raw query this should work:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM Car WHERE color='Black') AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT name FROM Car WHERE color='Red') AS b
ON (a.name=b.name)
```